# Dovecot v2.2.9 mysql user query issue

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to setup a Dovecot and postfix e-mail server. now, i was able to authenticate correctly, but when I open up /var/log/dovecot.log, I get this:

```
Jun 18 23:20:10 auth-worker(17531): Error: sql(aj@example.com,1.1.1.1): User query failed: Unknown column 'home' in 'field list' (using built-in default user_query: SELECT home, uid, gid FROM users WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d')
```

What should i do?

Comment: Post the structure of the `users` db table

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing the column `home` in your users table. You will also need `gid` and `uid` fields for this query.

Dovecot may be able to determine these values by other means.  Dovecot may be able to use other mechanisms to determine these values.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that when it used the default query, I was able to receive e-mail, How would I remove that message from spamming my dovecot.log file?

Comment: @ajanneh You could add the columns to the table you are querying, or use a view which provides values for the table.   Alternatively use a custom query.  You don't explain why you are using a database for authentication, so I can't provide much more help.  I use a passdb file based authentication, which does not seem to have this issue.

Comment: On my postfix+dovecot+mysql set up, the end location for the mail is determined by the username and hostname the email is composed of, the only query in dovecot is for authentication...

Comment: @ivanivan It sounds like you are doing heavy virtualization with multiple servers. It that is the case, you should take the time to review the Dovecot Wiki to understand what you need to do.  If you are only authenticating, then it is likely appropriate to use a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, thats because user not found in virtual_users table. i added with below mysql: 
INSERT INTO `servermail`.`virtual_users`
(`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
(NULL, '1', ENCRYPT('YourPassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'your@email');

Comment: I strongly doubt that inserting a record into a table is going to modify the schema to add a column.